# Django Project/Site--CSS changes appear on Safari not on Chrome

Tags: html, css, django, google-chrome, safari

I need some help. I prepare to change my site and working on a django project. The thing is the fact that all the changes i am doing in the static files go through correctly in Safari, but are not visible in Chrome. Do you know why this happens?

Please see below the image from Chrome. What you see white in the image is in fact, the image not going through Chrome.

Also can someone please share with me some resources where i can find a blog/site where they teach you how to find correctly the CSS locator, while doing Inspect Element in the browser, in order to change different CSS attributes for images etc? I will owe you a lot! Maybe i am doing something which is not ok.

Please find below the part from the base.html

```
{%  extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{#{% block head_title %} {% endblock %}#}
{% block content %}

<div class="container-fluid" id="primapagina" style="background-image: url('{% static "img/shutterstock_4.jpg"%}')">
      <img id="our_logo" src={% static "/img/lastlogo.png" %}>
      <p id="banner-text">
```

Lore Ipsum etc

```
</div>

{%  endblock %}
```

Please find below my CSS code:

```
.container-fluid {
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
}

textarea {
    height: 66px;
}

#banner-text{
    color: white;
}

#our_logo{
    height: 46px;
}
```

My settings:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "static_root")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro", "our_static"),)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env", "media_root")

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error cached the page.
I followed this post https://forums.realmacsoftware.com/t/chrome-wont-refresh-updated-page-without-clearing-cache/12113/3

If you do want to do a ‘hard refresh’ of your website cache in Chrome (without effecting other websites you browse to) open the web inspector in Chrome. Then right-click the refresh button and select Hard Reload from the menu.